# RSS feed : wrong encoding?

Tags: rss

I just migrated my website to a brand new server, and now i'm having a weird issue.

Some characters on my RSS feed are not properly encoded, as you can see here : http://www.windowsphonefr.com/mise-a-jour-de-facebook-sur-windows-phone-8-des-performances-au-top/20392/feed

The characters affected are <, >, ', and ". Accented (á, é, ê, à, è, ...) are correctly displayed.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Looks fine to me in FeedDemon and Safari, and the W3 feed validator says it's perfectly valid. Did you resolve this yourself already?

Comment: Looks OK to me too. Can you cut/paste a section that is "wrongly encoded"?

Comment: @Su' It is not correctly displayed in IE on Windows 8 (Modern UI app, not desktop). On the previous server, characters like __'__ were properly displayed. Today they are replaced by "&#039;". This really bother me as the Windows Phone app of my website uses theses feeds. :-/

Comment: Have you tried another app to read the feed. As @Su' said w3 validated it which means it's ok. You can test it here http://validator.w3.org/appc/

Comment: The problem would seem to be that you have entities inside your CDATA sections which you don't want encoded. This might be OK if your feed is displayed in an HTML context, but if not (which seems to be the case) these entities should be displayed literally - unless the reader manually decodes these entities (which it should not). Since your CDATA sections contain a mixture of encoded and unencoded chars I would guess that the encoded chars are in your source data, or another process is encoding them. I don't see how the server itself can influence this.

Comment: A bit of an aside, but... why is the W3 validator not throwing an error on the unencoded ampersand (`&`) in the first `description` tag when validating by URL? Yet it does when validating the XML by direct input.

Comment: @w3d OK, so WordPress is now mixing encoded and unencoded chars since the last update (3.5)...

Comment: Looks ok to me as well

Comment: Too little information...

Answer (score 1):

Those characters affected are the ones that are usually encoded as HTML entities: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos` and `&quot;`.  Maybe you need to decode them first?